# Vertex paint does it have any use?

Tags: vertex-paint-mode

Can I bake vertex painted models into flat textures to export in other programs?
If not what exactly is the use of vertex painting mode?

Comment: I am 90% sure you can make vertex colors to image textures. If not, vertex colors are accessible to materials, and it is basically useful as another way to store data besides vertex groups.

Comment: Yes, the vertex colors can be baked to a texture with the *Vertex Color* node in the shader editor. Vertex colors are useful for coloring high-poly sculptures. Or to create a dirt map (menu).